# В каком разрешении должен быть дизайн?

Tags: android, java

В каком разрешении должен быть дизайн макета для андроид, чтобы он правильно отображался в mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi? И как узнать что картинка hdpi xhdpi или mdpi

---

Насчет иконок я знаю, там даже программа есть специальная которая сама делит под все типы экранов иконку, но тут дело о картинке, допустим размер 500 на 500. Если оригинал 500 на 500 использовать в xxhdpi то она будет растянута и 9 path тут не поможет, ведь 9 path используется для не залитого или однообразной картинки, а в данной картинке свыше 200 цветов.

Неужели нет стандарта в Андроид разработке для дизайнеров)), чтобы они знали в каком разрешении нужно рисовать....

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: (x)DPI - свойство не изображений. Оно относится только к экрану. Это его плотность. У изображений есть только РАЗРЕШЕНИЕ.

Comment: А вообще ваш вопрос объясняется в любом курсе уроков по Android-разработке. Советую вам сначала научиться хотя бы основам, а потом уже браться за разработку. Сразу отпадут все глупые вопросы, вроде этого.

Comment: Почему же глупые то вопросы?

Вот есть картинка 40 на 40 на дисплее mdpi она будет смотреться нормально как маленькая картинка. А вот если использовать её в xhdpi она вообще же будет как точка. Так вот все же. В каком разрешении нужно рисовать для дизайнера? чтобы везде была нормальная?

Comment: Для нормального отображения всяких иконок и т.д. рисуются несколько вариантов под разные xDPI, посмотрите ,как отрисованы иконки в http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html
Так же обратите внимание, что в дереве каталогов ресурсов приложения есть множество папок drawble с указанием нужного xDPI, картинки под определенный дисплей кладутся в определенную папочку, а сам механизм отрисовки графики в дальнейшем сам выбирает из какой папочки брать картиночки для отображения

Answer (score 1):

Для различных разрешений экрана используются папки drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi и пр.. Существует аналогичное деление для размеров экрана: drawable-normal, drawable-large и т.д.. Можно совмещать эти способы и создавать папки типа drawable-normal-hdpi. Для изображений, которые должны оставаться неизменными вне зависимости от разрешения экрана, следует создать папку drawable-nodpi.

Для памятки приведу используемые размеры изображений для значков и фона экрана:

res/drawable-ldpi - (120 DPI) (QVGA):
ic_launcher.png (значок), 36 × 36 background.png (фон), 320 × 240 pixels

res/drawable-mdpi - (160 DPI) (HVGA):
background.png, 320 × 480

res/drawable-hdpi - (240 DPI) (WVGA):
ic_launcher.png, 72 × 72
background.png, 800 × 480

res/drawable-xhdpi (320 DPI) (WSVGA or HDTV):
ic_launcher.png, 96 × 96
background.png, 1024 × 600 или 1280 × 720 pixels